# High pitch sound from tv conected to hdmi

Tags: 14.04, sound, hdmi, tv

Audio does work but there is a high pitched sound coming from the tv when it is connected and selected as sound output via hdmi in ubuntu 14.04. I have not tinkered with any drivers or sound configs. I don't know why it does this as this problem is not present in windows 8.

I really want to use ubuntu instead of windows. Any ideas?